# How to edit and set the Zedgraph scale limits using mouse based events?

Tags: set, scale, zedgraph, limits

I want to **set the Zedgraph scale limits from the user interface level** using mouse based events, with the help of following code I could change the scale values pro-grammatically,

> ```
>        GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
> ```

```
        // Set Min & Max of X-Axis Scale
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
        myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = 100;
        myPane.AxisChange();
```

but I'm trying to provide an option to the end user, so that he or she could place the mouse over the scale values and change the limits dynamically.

**Edit:**

[image]

***Simple Thought:*** *We should be able to change the scale limits by simply clicking the mouse twice on those scale limits(0.0 or 1.2).*

your ideas & suggestions are appreciated & thanks for your time....:)

Comment: Do you mean you want to change what is visible on your graph (i.e. you want to zoom in)?

Comment: I added another suggestion to my answer, I think it should work :)

Comment: I am curious if you tried my new answer or if you found some other solution to this problem.

Comment: I have tried this method long time ago, but no luck...:( May be I was missing something, Utilizing Mouse Click Event + Checking the locations isn't sufficient to implement this, I thought it requires some more information to access the image(Graph).... Please correct me if I'm wrong...?

Comment: I was thinking the following pseudo code:
`if((cursor.X < (chart.Location.X + chart.Size.X * 0.9) && (cursor.X > (chart.Location.X + chart.Size.X * 0.8))` and the same thing for the Y direction. This way you can say you are in that range of the chart. You will have to use the location of the chart on the screen too. I know that there are some syntax errors in that code shown above. Is this what you tried?

Comment: I appreciate your time on this issue, as mentioned in my earlier comment, the issue is not at this level(whether the mouse click is on scale or not), one step further.... Let's just consider we've done everything to make sure the mouse clicked twice, located at first element of the XScale &&&&& This is where I stuck with no answer??!!?? You've mentioned that pop up box, it's a good idea but I wanted to do it in a different way(Editing Text + Enter on the chart itself)

Comment: What about creating a `TextBox` and making its location at the right location? Then the user can input text and once they click enter then you can `Dispose` of the `TextBox`? Or else you can create a form and just make its size very, very small (this way it is easier to maintain user focus) with a `TextBox` on it?

Comment: This would be the best & simple solution.... I'll give a try....Thanks a lot...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of doing is utilizing the `MouseClick` event and then trying to pull off a big dirty hack. I would check the `Location` property of the graph (that will usually give you the upper left coordinate) and then by checking the `Size` property (do this in case your window has changed size and so has your graph) and then get your [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx). If the cursor is over the scale values then maybe have a pop-up show where they can enter their new `Max` or `Min` values? Figuring out roughly where the scale values are shown in a dynamically changing graph might be a nuisance but it can definitely be done, especially if you sit down and do the math to find at what percentage of the size the labels are shown.

I hope this helps!

EDIT: Also make sure it is the left button being clicked:

```
 if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, However I was looking to change the 'scale limits' and not the 'zoom' function. Please Have a look at my 'Edit' section.